# Converting predicted random forest results into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, regression, random-forest

This question may look silly, but I did not get an idea, so I need your help.

I used `RandomForestRegressor()` to predict the result and wrote the following codes:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

      
# create a regressor object
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100, random_state = 0)
      
# fit the regressor with x and y data
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
Y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

`Y_pred` is the result for a given `X_test`. Now, I would like to create a data frame of my `Y_pred` and `y_test` data and save it into CSV format.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems quite simple, just clicked into my mind. So this way, it can be done:

```py
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'x':Y_pred, 'y':y_test})
df_new.head()
```